# Submit form from a button tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events, submit

I added an event listener when my form is submitted, this is the code:

```
var formo = document.getElementById("ing");
formo.addEventListener("submit", validation, false);
```

but I'm submitting the form with a button tag with this code:

```
var enviar = document.getElementById("submit_btn");
enviar.addEventListener("click", envioFormulario, false);

function envioFormulario() {
  this.disabled = true;
  this.value = "Sending";
  this.form.submit();
}
```

with this the form is submitted but the submit event (the first lines of code) doesn't seems to work what can I do to make it work?

Comment: Why not have your click handler fire the validation?

Comment: This may be off-base, so I won't submit it as an answer, but I sometimes have problems firing events inside event handlers. What happens if you replace the line firing the submit event with `var myForm = this.form; setTimeout(function() { myForm.submit(); }, 0);`?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Mathletics comment. Just do the validation when you click, and submit if it passes validation:

```
var enviar = document.getElementById("submit_btn");
enviar.addEventListener("click", envioFormulario, false);

function envioFormulario() {
  if (validation()) {
      this.disabled = true;
      this.value = "Sending";
      this.form.submit();
  } else {
      alert("Validation failed. Didn't submit");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the function name in the "onsubmit" attribute of your form element.

Comment: Also remember to return false if you want to bail out of the submit.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be around preventing the default behaviour from occuring.

You need to receive the event in your handler function to do that.

```
function validation( event )
{
  if ( event.preventDefault ) event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;
  // continue validating
}
```